# elastic search tasks api returns index not found

Tags: elasticsearch, task

I use tasks API for Elasticsearch 6.8. reindex process for my project. Sometimes I face the issue when in some of elastic search installations this API doesn't work properly. For example I create reindex task by command:

```
 POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
  {
  "source": {
  "index": "index1"

  },
  "dest": {
  "index": "index2"
  }
}
```

As response I get task Id.
But when I try to check status of this tasks by command

`GET _tasks/{task-id}`

instead of task status like in normal case I recieve the following:

```
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [{
                "type": "index_not_found_exception",
                "reason": "no such index",
                "resource.type": "index_expression",
                "resource.id - Registered at Namecheap.com ": ".tasks",
                "index_uuid": "na",
                "index": ".tasks"
            }
        ],
        "type": "resource_not_found_exception",
        "reason": "task [epsVDuiBRO-IJBqCB2zHXQ:974632] isn't running and hasn't stored its results",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "index_not_found_exception",
            "reason": "no such index",
            "resource.type": "index_expression",
            "resource.id - Registered at Namecheap.com ": ".tasks",
            "index_uuid": "na",
            "index": ".tasks"
        }
    },
    "status": 404
}
```

Is there any way to recover tasks API without reinstalling Elastic? I haven't succeed to find it in documentation.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved. The issue was related to our own mapping with index patterns "*". It seems that by default elasticsearch doesn't create .tasks index. It creates it only when first command using tasks API performed adding new task document to this index. In my case it ElasticSearch couldn't add first .tasks  document because some of fields of this document conflicted with the same fields from our own mapping. Solution is to change pattern of our mapping, or explicitly create mapping for .tasks index before putting our own mapping.